# Проблема позиционирования списка

Tags: html, css, позиционирование, ul

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему список прижимается к нижней границе родительского элемента, поднимается вверх при добавлении новой строчки и как все-таки прижать к верхней границе?

```css
.footer {
  height: 290px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.footer .footerMenu {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 390px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.footer ul {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

.footer #column2 {
  margin: 0 120px 0 220px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.footer #column3 {
  margin-right: 145px;
}

.footer li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.footer li p {
  font-family: "Lucida Grande";
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #A4A4A4;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.footer #headFooter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #5A5A5A;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<section class="footer">
  <div class="footerMenu">
    <ul id="column1">
      <li>
        <p id="headFooter">address</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>60 Adress str,<br>FL 33134</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/phone.png" alt="" style="margin: 0 14px 0 5px;">
        <p>Phone: 305 447 6633</p><br>
        <img src="img/email.png" alt="" style="margin-right: 10px;">
        <p>Email: info@gmail.com</p>
      </li>
      <!-- <li><p></p><br><br></li> -->

    </ul>
    <ul id="column2">
      <li>
        <p id="headFooter">company</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Home</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Wedding</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Baby</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Quinces/Bar/Bat</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Social</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="column3">
      <li>
        <p></p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Product/Services</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Online Consultation</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Blog</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>White Papers</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Contact us</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="column4">
      <li>
        <p id="headFooter">newsletter</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Sign up for news & special offers!</p>
      </li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/kog1texj/1/)

Answer (score 2):

```
  .footer ul {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
```

При `inline-block`, чтобы выровнить нужно использовать  `vertical-align: top;`

Ты использовал, но не совсем там, я точно не знаю зачем оно там, но так они выровняются